# Does the consistency of $\sf NF$ enable us to transfer its cardinal comparisons to the inside of $\sf Z$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, new-foundations

I think that stratified comprehension has the potential to breach Cantor's arguments about the relative size of sets and their powers, this has been done to an extent in $\sf NFU$ and the known consistent extensional fragments of $\sf NF$, where non-Cantorian sets can have their power sets equal to them in size or even the extensional version of their power sets being strictly lower; and in some weak fragments (the predicative ones) even all infinite Cantorian sets can be equal in size with their power sets. However here I want to tranfer this to the milieu of Zermelo, by working in a restricted version of Zermelo after stratification criterion, so instead of full separation we have a stratified separation, the rest of axioms of $\sf ZF-Replacement$ can be kept, add an axiom that each set is a member of a stage of the cumulative hierarchy, which is indeed definable without Replacement. This to be termed as "$\sf Str.Z$".

If we presume that (working in $\sf ZF-Reg.$ as the background theory of models) we can have a transitive non-well-founded model $M$ of  "$\sf str.Z$" such that there exists a non-standard ordinal (a transitive set strictly totally ordered by $\in$, that is not a von Neumann ordinal externally speaking but that $M$ sees as a von Neumann ordinal) $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ is equal in size to its successor stage $V_{\alpha+1}$, or even perhaps having all higher stages being equal in size to that of $V_\alpha$, and by the equality of size here I mean internally speaking, that is, as seen internally inside $M$. Since we have full stratified separation satisfied by $M$, then we will at the same time have a form of Cantor's argument still surviving internally in $M$, that is, $M \models|P(x)|>|P_1(x)|$, which entails that all stages that are equinumerous to their successor stages, must be non-Cantorian; that is, the restriction of the singleton map $x \mapsto \{x\}$ to any of these stages is not a set in $M$. This would transfer the cardinal comparison experience of non-Cantorian sets in $\sf NF$ to the inside of $\sf Z$.

What presents itself as a question here is:

> Does $\sf Con(NF)$ entail the consistency of $${\sf ZF-Reg.} + \\\exists M: M \models \sf (str.Z + \exists \alpha: |V_\alpha|=|V_{\alpha+1}|)$$ ?

One can easily show that the opposite is true: take any of the equinumerous cumulative stages in $M$ and take an internal bijection $j$ from it to the next stage, define a new membership relation $x \in^j y \iff x \in j(y)$, then $\langle \operatorname {dom}(j),\in^j \rangle$ would be a model of $\sf NF$! One can check this easily by taking any finite axiomatization of $\sf NF$.